# How can I pass in a string and use that as a variable name?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I have a variable such as:

```
var startX = 20
var startY = 30
```

I want to call a function such as:

```
onClick="myFunction('startX')"
or
onClick="myFunction('startY')"

myFunction(passedVar){
}
```

So passedVar = 'startX' or 'startY' and I then need to reference the variable of the same name and get it's value (20 or 30)

In Powershell I'd do a:

```
get-variable($passedVar) -value
```

which would see what's in passedVar and then look for a variable with that name and give me the value.

Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `myFunction('startX', startX)` ?

Comment: Where is the variable defined? Global? Inside of the function? In an enclosing scope of the function?

Comment: well, I guess that'd just be too easy.
@Thilo I think I found that one of the variables was originally set in a function.  I moved it out and I think I have it working better now.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are just properties of the `window` object. You could try

```
var val = window[passedVar];
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to omit the single quotes; it is not required.

onClick="myFunction(startX)"
or
onClick="myFunction(startY)"